# CMake Linking Header Only Library (Working Example) for which I want explanation

Tags: c++, cmake

I am learning how to use **ExternalProject** to download header only libaries and link to my executable.

My workflow is following:

1. I download header library Eigen using ExtenalProject:

> cmake -DGET_LIBS=ON  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS=OFF -G
> "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64  .. && cmake --build . --config Release

2. Then I run the same CMakeLists a second time, but this time I disable ExternalProject and compile the executable that links the Eigen:

> cmake -DGET_LIBS=OFF  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS=ON
> -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64  ..  && cmake  --build . --config Release

**Question**

Why I need to use both of these commands since in `target_include_directories` command I specify the same path as in `include_directories`?

In the code below I need two commands `include_directories` and `target_include_directories`.
I thought that it would be enough to use only `target_include_directories`, but without `include_directories` it wont work.

```
if (BUILD_MY_PROJECTS)
add_executable(my_exe main.cpp)


include_directories("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/") #add directory of the header-only library without this the next line wort work
target_include_directories(my_exe INTERFACE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/")# link exe to exectable
endif ()
```

My full CMakeLists.txt is following:

```
project(superbuild LANGUAGES CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

########################################################################
# EIGEN
########################################################################
SET(GET_LIBS "" CACHE STRING "Set option to download dependencies")
if (GET_LIBS)
  message(AUTHOR_WARNING ${GET_LIBS})
  ExternalProject_Add(eigen
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
    GIT_TAG 3.4.0
    CMAKE_ARGS
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
      -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen #this does nothing...
    SOURCE_DIR   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen" #install in my local build dir
    #SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    BUILD_COMMAND "" #do not build
    INSTALL_COMMAND "" #do not install
  )

endif ()


###############################################################################
#EXECUTABLES
###############################################################################
if (BUILD_MY_PROJECTS)
add_executable(my_exe main.cpp)


include_directories("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/") #add directory of the header-only library without this the next line wort work
target_include_directories(my_exe INTERFACE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/")# link exe to exectable
endif ()
```

Comment: Header only libraries typically don't require linking anything additionally. That's why they're named so.

Comment: This is not my question.

Comment: Since you're using `target_include_directories` with `INTERFACE` visibility, the include dir would be added to any target linking `my_exe`, but not for `my_exe` itself. `target_include_directories` has zero effect in this scenario. You need to use `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC` visibilities...

Comment: @fabian
Thanks it means, it works without, it is enough only to use  **include_directories("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/")** ?

Comment: I'd recommend to "attach" the info to the `my_exe` target using `target_include_directories(my_exe PRIVATE ("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/")` and removing `include_directories`. For `include_directories` it's imho just to easy to forget/overlook that the change applies to all targets that are created in the same directory and in any subdir added using `add_subdirectories` afterwards.

Comment: But your first sentence in your comment, does not work without include_directores. Isn't it? As was mentioned in my original question. Or it works just because of PRIVATE keyword rather than INTERFACE?

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr **never use `include_directories`**. Ever. Learn how property visibility works in CMake instead.

---

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/") #add directory of the header-only library without this the next line wort work
target_include_directories(my_exe INTERFACE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/")# link exe to exectable
```

In the code you supplied, `include_directories` is implicitly setting the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property on your `my_exe` target. Then the second line sets the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property.

`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is a list of include directories that must be passed to the compiler when building the target. `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is a list of include directories that must be passed to the compiler when building *targets that link to this one*. This doesn't make much sense for an executable

Slightly better would be to write:

```
target_include_directories(my_exe PRIVATE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/")
```

This will just populate `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` without touching the `INTERFACE_` version. If you wanted both you could write `PUBLIC` instead of `PRIVATE` or `INTERFACE`. By definition, `PUBLIC` is just both of the others.

---

But this isn't a great dependency management strategy anyway... digging into the source tree guts of a project isn't scalable. It's also difficult to try different versions of Eigen without editing your build files.

I would just write:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(example)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(my_exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_exe PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)
```

Use a proper package manager like vcpkg or Conan to handle downloading Eigen when it isn't available on the system.

Comment: It means that you do not suggest to use external project but rather install libraries individually to C:/ProgramFiles in order to use find_package?

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) install globally to program files. Install to a local folder, underneath the build directory even, and point `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` at it.

Comment: Does the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is what find_package is looking at?

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL - please see the documentation for the find_package search procedure, here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html